# How to fix this visual glitch which causes flickering and GameObjects duplicating in scene view?

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

This started happening after I changed to URP , also note that the project is old from 2015 and was made in editor 5.3.1f, I changed the editor version to latest 2021 LTS community version, all other scenes are working fine with URP except this one I also tried stacking the cameras but it didn't fix the issue

[image: problem]

Comment: Is your cameras clear flag set to sky or color?

Comment: there is no clear flag option on the camera inspector...after i changed to URP...but the camera which is set to overlay does have it's clear depth option enabled in the inspector...but that doesn't help at all...

Comment: That is quite peculiar. I've been using URP for a while and there should always be a clear flag. This must be something strange with the upgrade to the latest version of unity. The numbered versions of Unity are a lot older then my expertise. Perhaps you will have to manually remake the faulty camera object.

Comment: I just did what you said and it still doesn't contain the clear flag property ,what's more weird is that even if I delete the second camera the issue still remains.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on the Unity Forum and toss in the package of the broken scene for good measure.

Comment: well I solved the problem see the answer section, weirdly but it was the skybox material that was causing the problem, maybe because it wasn't compatible but hope this helps other's...thanks anyways @Voidsay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: it was the Environmental settings under the lightning settings. Although I just changed the `skybox material` to `none,` and that solved the issue, I think it wasn't in some way compatible with URP.